# Gradle - what to do if your runtime environment uses different Jars?

Tags: java, gradle, plugins

I have gone through this problem twice and wondering if there is a solution for it:

Let's say I have a project `Project` which depends on `SomeClass`. `SomeClass` depends on `Dependency` version `n`.

Now let's say `Project` gets deployed as a plugin/sub-program or separate runnable in some environment. The environment is itself a program (let's say I am writing a plugin into a program) and it depends on `Dependency` version `m`, where `m` < `n`. When deployed the environment will use the safest version of `Dependency`, in this case `m`, as not to crash the main program. However, since I have methods in my plug-in that are present in version `n` but not `m`, I now get a MethodNotFoundException.

Is there a way to package the plugin `Project` so that it uses `n` and the program can still use `m`? Maybe like a module rename?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125833/two-dependencies-use-the-same-library-but-with-different-versions. only one version is used, according to the answer in the link.

Comment: You can bundle and relocate packages of your dependencies so they won't conflict with the general runtime environment. The only annoying thing is that you will need to load either your application or the dependent classes through a special classlader (as they have been relocated). Maybe through something like the [shadow plugin for Gradle](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding out about the [Shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/), so [Bjorn Vester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1703730/bj%C3%B8rn-vester)'s comment is correct above.

In my `build.gradle` I did

```
shadowJar {
    relocate 'com.reference.to.dependency', 'myprojectreference.shadow.reference.to.dependency'
}
```

(Note that the second argument to relocate doesn't have to match a specific pattern - I use my project's reference to avoid accidentally creating new collisions along with `shadow`).

And my new shadow jar worked fine.